# Increment and update value in the total number after insert new rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, increment, decrement

EDIT: I have updated the code with the answers.

I have a increment function that is working fine. However:

*1. I would like to set some limits based on the total number available in one of the span. For example, 10. So the incrementing can't be more than 10. #DONE*

2. Another issue is that I am planning to have multiple rows and before I save I want to make sure if we count the increments in every row it should not be more than 10 as well. If it decrease the total number (span) dynamically would be nice.

I'm adding rows dynamically with the ADD button, how can I add news rows that actually work with the current functions? Mine rows just clone the first one and the increment function is disabled.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
  document.querySelector('#addlocationdest').addEventListener('click', add);
});
function add() {
    var x = 1;
    var container = document.getElementById('destination');
    var detail = document.getElementById('row');
    var clone = detail.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "destination" + x;
    x++;
    container.appendChild(clone);

}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let elTotalQuantity = document.querySelector("#totalqty");
  let totalQuantity = parseInt(elTotalQuantity.innerHTML);
  
  function getSumOfRows() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let input of document.querySelectorAll("form .row > input.quantity"))
      sum += parseInt(input.value);
    return sum;
  }
  
  for (let row of document.querySelectorAll("form .row")) {
    let input = row.querySelector("input");
    row.querySelector(".increment").addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (getSumOfRows() >= totalQuantity) return;
      input.value++;
      elTotalQuantity.innerHTML = totalQuantity - getSumOfRows();
    });
    row.querySelector(".decrement").addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (input.value <= 0) return;
      input.value--;
      elTotalQuantity.innerHTML = totalQuantity - getSumOfRows();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="location" class="hide">
                    <div class="title">Transfer details</div><br>
                    <div class="line padded-s">Total Quantity: <span>10</span></div>
                    <br>
                        <form>
                            <label>New Total Quantity at this location: <span id="totalqty">10</span></label>
                            <br>
                            <div id="destination">
                                <div id="row" class="row">
                                    <button type="button" class="decrement">-</button>
                                    <input type="text" class="quantity" value="0" readonly/>
                                    <button type="button" class="increment">+</button>
                                    <a>Location: </a>
                                    <input type="text" class="location" value="0" readonly/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <label>Total being transfer: <p id="total-sum"></p></label>
                        <br>
                        <button type="button" id="addlocationdest">ADD</button>
            <button type="button" id="removelocationdest">REMOVE</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Will the number for the total quantity be dynamic? And what number should be reduced if it overflows the total quantity number after submitting the form? Can't you NOT increase the number of a row, when increasing it would make the actual total quantity overflow the given total quantity number?

Comment: yes the total number would be dynamic, the total number will be reduced and the other allocate to specific rows in the database, but for now that is not important. When I increase the number in a row it will reduce the total number, The total number is for reference. Think on that as a current quantity in that specific location

Comment: So the total number is not the total number of the numbers below, but the total number that can still be distributed to the numbers below?

Comment: that's it that number will be distributed and needs to be updated accordingly

Comment: Should it be possible to write a number into the input-field by keyboard, or should it only be possible to change the value with the buttons? Allowing the change by keyboard would make it quite a bit more complicated, however still possible.

Comment: I don't really need to write a number, just the button is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prologue**
As long as the total quantity is fixed at the beginning of the script-execution, this works. Otherwise, it would be best to save the actual allowed total quantity as an attribute, and observe it using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). That way you can update your max. value in your code dynamically, when the total quantity-attribute changes.  You can define [custom attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) by naming them "data-*" where "*" is a custom name.

**Solution for your problem**
You are using the same ID on multiple elements. What you meant were classes, so change `id="increment"` to `class="increment"`, and the same for `decrement`.

Since we don't want to input something with the buttons, but add listener to them, I'd say it is better to actually use `<button>`. In forms, buttons act as `type="submit"`, which we don't want, so we need to change it to `type="button"`.

Since the rows and the total quantity actually belong together, it is wiser to place them together into **one** `<form>`-element. However, you can still group the buttons and inputs as a row together using `<div>`.

Now regarding the in-/decrementing of the row's values and the total quantity:

1. Save the allowed total quantity in a variable
2. Add event-listener to the corresponding buttons
3. If action is valid, change row's value
4. Update total quantity number to `totalQuantity - getSumOfRows()`

To add new rows dynamically, we create and setup such an element, and append it to the form. See the `appendNewRow()`-function below.

**Sidenote**
I have added the `readonly` attribute to the input-fields so that you cannot enter numbers via keyboard.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let elTotalQuantity = document.querySelector("#totalqty");
  let totalQuantity = parseInt(elTotalQuantity.innerHTML);
  
  function getSumOfRows() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let input of document.querySelectorAll("form .row > input.quantity"))
      sum += parseInt(input.value);
    return sum;
  }
  function updateTotalQuantity() {
      elTotalQuantity.innerHTML = totalQuantity - getSumOfRows();
  }
  
  function appendNewRow() {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");
    let child;
    
    // input.quantity
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.classList.add("quantity");
    input.value = "0";
    input.setAttribute("readonly", "");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    row.append(input);
    
    // button.increment
    child = document.createElement("button");
    child.classList.add("increment");
    child.innerHTML = "+";
    child.setAttribute("type", "button");
    child.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (getSumOfRows() >= totalQuantity) return;
      input.value++;
      updateTotalQuantity();
    });
    row.append(child);
    
    // button.increment
    child = document.createElement("button");
    child.classList.add("decrement");
    child.innerHTML = "-";
    child.setAttribute("type", "button");
    child.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (input.value <= 0) return;
      input.value--;
      updateTotalQuantity();
    });
    row.append(child);
    
    // button.remove-row
    child = document.createElement("button");
    child.classList.add("remove-row");
    child.innerHTML = "Remove";
    child.setAttribute("type", "button");
    child.addEventListener("click", () => {
      row.remove();
      updateTotalQuantity();
    });
    row.append(child);
    
    document.querySelector("form .rows").append(row);
  }
  
  document.querySelector("form .add-row").addEventListener("click", () => appendNewRow());
  
  appendNewRow();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Total Quantity: <span id="totalqty">10</span></label>
  <br>
  <div class="rows">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="add-row">Add new row</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If we add a second input in the row, the total quantity returns NaN after the first increment

Comment: You can give the input that holds the quantity a class like `quantity`, and query for that. That way, it should work.  
Updated the answer to incorporate what i just said.

Comment: How can I send the values in the rows to the database? I'm thinking in to use something like SELECT * FROM mytable where itemID=?? & location=??.. if returns 1 -> UPDATE the value and if returns 0 -> INSERT and create new row

Comment: Looks like you are using a SQL-database.
Your idea seems good enough for what I think you are trying to achieve. But for a better answer you should open a new question.

Comment: Yes, indeed I am using MySQL Thank you so much, if you wanna have a look at the question here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761304/inserting-updating-in-mysql-table-through-node-js-and-restify

Answer (score 1):

QuerySelector only selects the first occurrence so you haven't really added a listener to the second "row". You should use querySelectorAll but, instead of unique ids, use classes.

```
<input class="increment" type="button" value="+" />
```

1. Now you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".increment")` to get all elements in an array.
2. You can traverse in the DOM by using `parentElement`. By knowing which button you clicked, you can traverse up to the form element and then select the first child - which is an input. A more dynamic way would be to use `querySelector` to select the input, in case the HTML change in the future. Anyway, that's how you can know which input to manipulate based on where the buttons are in the DOM.
3. I added two global variables, `totalSum` and `maxSum`. *maxSum* is fetched from your span element (which I assigned an unique id to). *totalSum* makes sure that all inputs combined doesn't exceed *maxSum*.
4. You had some duplicate code, so I refactored it into a new method: `changeValue`.

In all, I think the code speaks for itself.

Oh, this code doesn't take into account that the user can change the value inside the input. I will leave that for you to figure out with an "oninput" listener on each text input.

```js
var totalSum = 0;  // 3
var maxSum = 0
var totalSumElement = null;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
  totalSumElement = document.getElementById('total-sum');
  maxSum = document.getElementById('max-sum').innerText;

  var incrementElements = document.querySelectorAll('.increment');  // 1
  var decrementElements = document.querySelectorAll('.decrement');

  addListener('click', incrementElements, incrementValue);
  addListener('click', decrementElements, decrementValue);
});


function addListener(type, elementArr, func) {
  for (element of elementArr) {
    element.addEventListener(type, func);
  }
}

function withinRange(newValue) {
  var maxReached  = newValue > maxSum;  // 3
  var zeroReached = newValue < 0;

  return !maxReached && !zeroReached;
}

function changeValue(event, change) {  // 4
  if (withinRange(totalSum + change)) {
    let parent = event.currentTarget.parentElement;  // 2
    let input  = parent.children[0];
    let value  = parseInt(input.value) || 0;
    
    if (withinRange(value + change)) {
      input.value = value + change;
      totalSum = totalSum + change;
    }
  }

  totalSumElement.textContent = `Total: ${totalSum}`;
}

function incrementValue(event) {
  changeValue(event, 1);
}

function decrementValue(event) {
  changeValue(event, -1);
}
```

```css
#totalqty {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="totalqty" class="line padded-s">Total Quantity: <span id="max-sum">10</span></div>

<form>
  <input type="text" value="0" />
  <input class="increment" type="button" value="+" />
  <input class="decrement" type="button" value="-" />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="0" />
  <input class="increment" type="button" value="+" />
  <input class="decrement" type="button" value="-" />
</form>

<p id="total-sum"></p>
```

Comment: I already have a function called addListener and if I rename yours I got an error ReferenceError: element is not defined

Comment: You need to debug if that's the case. Add a `debugger;` to your renamed `addListener` method and run the page with the Web Developer Console open in the browser. For some reason, the `elementArr` is empty. You can also `console.log()` `incrementElements`and `decrementElements` to see if the arrays aren't empty.